# Why is this code generating a scala match exception

Tags: scala

I'm trying to compare two parallel arrays of strings together.  Each array is guaranteed to be the same length.  Corresponding strings in each array may be indented differently, so I perform a trim when comparing them.  I've written the following function to do the comparison, and I'm getting a match error when I run the code:

```
def compare(expected: Seq[String], actual: Seq[String]): Boolean = (expected, actual) match {
    case (Nil, _) => true
    case (a :: _, b :: _) if (a.trim != b.trim) => false
    case (_ :: a, _ :: b) => compare(a, b)
}
```

What am I missing here?  As far as I can tell this should cover all cases.

The actual exception:

```
 scala.MatchError: (WrappedArray(ExpectedString), WrappedArray(ActualString)) (of class scala.Tuple2)
```

Comment: If you are going to pattern match against Lists, you should receive lists instead of generic sequence as parameters. Maybe, when calling the method you are not passing a List but maybe an Array or Vector?

Comment: Please share your exception.

Comment: @MichaelZajac Both sequences are guaranteed to be the same length.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik added.

Comment: @Andy The error es pretty clear, you are passing a WrappedArray, but the method only works for Lists.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Why is that?

Comment: @Andy if you change the method signature to `def compare(expected: List[String], actual: List[String]): Boolean`. Then, it wont compile where you are using it, which is better than a runtime exception.